# How to write a random weighted sampler for pytorch?

Tags: pytorch

I have this function for weighted random sampler:

my dataset is defined like this:

```
class loadedDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.classes = sorted(os.listdir(self.root_dir))
        self.count = [len(os.listdir(self.root_dir + '/' + c)) for c in self.classes]
        #print('self.count')
        #print(self.count)
        self.acc_count = [self.count[0]]
        for i in range(1, len(self.count)):
                self.acc_count.append(self.acc_count[i-1] + self.count[i])
        # self.acc_count = [self.count[i] + self.acc_count[i-1] for i in range(1, len(self.count))]
        
     

    def __len__(self):
        l = np.sum(np.array([len(os.listdir(self.root_dir + '/' + c)) for c in self.classes]))
        return l
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        label = 1
        for i in range(len(self.acc_count)):
            if idx < self.acc_count[i]:
                label = i
                
                break
           

        class_path = self.root_dir + '/' + self.classes[label] 

        if label:
            file_path = class_path + '/' + sorted(os.listdir(class_path))[idx-self.acc_count[label]]
        else:
            file_path = class_path + '/' + sorted(os.listdir(class_path))[idx]

        _, file_name = os.path.split(file_path)

        frames = []
        #self.file_path = file_path
        # print os.listdir(file_path)
        file_list = sorted(os.listdir(file_path))
        # print file_list

        # v: maximum translation in every step
        v = 2
        offset = 0
        for i, f in enumerate(file_list):
           
            #frame = Image.open(file_path + '/' + f)
            #frame = np.load(file_path + '/' + f, allow_pickle="True")
            #print("f")
           # print(f)
            npyfile = os.path.join(file_path + '/' + f)
            frame = torch.load(npyfile)
            
            #translation
            offset += random.randrange(-v, v)
            offset = min(offset, 3 * v)
            offset = max(offset, -3 * v)
            #frame = frame.transform(frame.size, Image.AFFINE, (1, 0, offset, 0, 1, 0))
            if self.transform is not None:
                frame = self.transform[0](frame)
            frames.append(frame)
            
            
            if len(frames) == 8:
                break
        
        while len(frames) < 8:
            frames.append(frame)
        
        #print(len(frames))
        return frames, label, file_name
```

and I have loaded my dataset like this:

```
train_dataset = loadedDataset(traindir)
val_dataset = loadedDataset(valdir)
```

My inputs are set of frames. Some classes have higher number of set of frames and I want to deal with the imbalance. The logic behind weighted random sampler is easy to understand but I just can't wrap my head around on how to implement it with my code.